# Invoke-Command on remote computer with IP Address and credentials

Tags: powershell

All, I need help with a strange issue I am having with the Invoke-Command cmdlet.  If I use a hard-coded IP address for the -ComputerName to run a scriptblock on a remote computer, the scriptblock works.

This works:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-culture} -ComputerName 172.21.242.52 -Credential $Credential -Verbose
```

This doesn't:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture} -ComputerName $Server01 -Credential $Credential -Verbose
```

However, if I use a variable to store the IP address, the exact same PowerShell logic does not work and throws an error message "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty".

Any help would be appreciated!

Tim

Comment: Can you show the statement that assigns the name of the server to the variable `$Server01`?

Comment: Sure James - [string]$Server01="172.21.242.52"  .

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I tried the same thing but unfortunately was unable to reproduce your issue.  Your question is nicely worded, and it's a good ScriptBlock to use as an example, but I do suggest you edit your question and show just a little bit more code to add some context.

Comment: So the code worked for you without using the hard-code IP address and using the variable instead?

Comment: Yes, exactly - `Invoke-Command` worked by using a variable for ComputerName (and I've done it many times before).  Normally I'd suggest "chat' but unfortunately you don't have the reputation yet to enter chat (need at least 20).  Best suggestion I can give is to post a more-complete version, still minimal, but with as much code as necessary to reproduce the problem.  Maybe somebody else will see the problem.